# Simplification of $\frac{\left(\frac{6\ln^22x}{2x}\right)}{\left(\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

My textbook goes from

$$\frac{\left( \frac{6\ln^22x}{2x} \right)}{\left(\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)}$$

to:

$$\frac{6\ln^22x}{3\sqrt{x}}$$

I don't see how this is right. Could anyone explain?

Comment: Just what "$\ln^2 2x$" means is problematic.  Sometimes it means $\ln(\ln (2x))$ and sometimes it means $(\ln(2x))^2$.  I wouldn't use that expression at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac{6\ln^2(2x)}{2x}}{\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{6\ln^2(2x)}{2x}\cdot\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{3}=\frac{6\ln^2(2x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{3}=$$
$$\frac{2\ln^2(2x)}{x}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1}=\frac{2\ln^2(2x)\sqrt{x}}{x}=\frac{2\ln^2(2x)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\frac{6ln^22x}{2x}}{\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}} = \frac{6ln^22x}{2x} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{3} = \frac{3ln^22x}{x} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt{x}}{3} = \frac{6\sqrt{x}ln^22x}{3x} = \frac{6\ln^22x}{3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}$$

$$\frac{6\ln^22x}{3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} = \frac{6\ln^22x}{3} \cdot x^{1/2}/x^1 =  \frac{6\ln^22x}{3} \cdot x^{-1/2} =  \frac{6\ln^22x}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} = \frac{6\ln^22x}{3\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Well...

$\dfrac ab=a\times \dfrac 1b$

In your case $a=\frac{6\ln^22x}{2x}$ and $b=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Then... $\dfrac 1b=\dfrac{2\sqrt{x}}{3}$.

Can you go from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\left( \frac{6\ln^22x}{2x} \right)}{\left(\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)} = \frac{6\ln^2 2x}{2x} \cdot \frac{2\sqrt x}{3} $$

Then use $\dfrac 6 3 = 2$ and $\dfrac {\sqrt x} x = \dfrac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x \cdot\sqrt x} = \dfrac 1 {\sqrt x}$.

Answer (score 1):

The textbook has [rationalised the denominator](http://www.bbc.co.uk/education/guides/z7fbkqt/revision/2) for $\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}$ before simplifying further

i.e.

$$\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{3\times \sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}\times \sqrt{x}}= \frac{3\sqrt{x}}{2x}$$

Now Simplify:

$$ \frac{\left(\frac{6\ln^2 2x}{2x}\right)}{\left(\frac{3}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)}= \frac{\left(\frac{6\ln^2 2x}{2x}\right)}{\left(\frac{3\sqrt{x}}{2x}\right)} = \frac{6 \ln^2 2x}{3\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply denominator and numerator by $2x=2\sqrt x\cdot\sqrt x$  to obtain the given result.